# Showing Associativity and Commutativity of a binary operation given by a Cayley table

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, associativity, cayley-table

Let $*$ be a binary operation on the set $S:=\{0,1\}$ given by the following Cayley table:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
* & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
If I wish to show that this table is associative, how many different combinations of arguments do I have to show it for? Commutativity is easy to show because the table is symmetric along the main diagonal. However, I know since associativity and commutativity are universal properties, I am having trouble figuring out as stated: how many different combinations of arguments do I have to execute (e.g. $0*(0*1)=1*(0*0)$ to show $*$ is associative on the set $S$?

Comment: Associative means $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$; how many possibilities are there for $a, b, $ and $c?$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner would it be 16? Since there are 4 slots in the table and 2 choices per slot in the table, yielding 16 possibilities?

Comment: There are $2$ possibilities for $a$ ($a=0$ or $1$), $2$ for $b$, ...

Comment: @J.W.Tanner ahhhh I see, would it be 8 possibilities then? 2 possibilities for a, 2 for b, and 2 for c.... yielding 8?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for leading me through this example, it really helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associativity means that for all $a, b $ and $c$ in $S$, $(a * b) * c = a * (b * c).$

Since $S$ has only two elements,

there are only two possibilities to check for $a$, two for $b$, and two for $c$;

altogether, there are $2\times2\times2=8$ possibilities to check:

$(0*0)*0=0*(0*0)$

$(0*0)*1=0*(0*1)$

$(0*1)*0=0*(1*0)$

$(0*1)*1=0*(1*1)$

$(1*0)*0=1*(0*0)$

$(1*0)*1=1*(0*1)$

$(1*1)*0=1*(1*0)$ and

$(1*1)*1=1*(1*1)$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to case-by-case checking (which does require $8$ checks), you could note that $a*b \equiv a+b \pmod{2}$.  Then you get that $*$ is associative because modular addition is associative.

Comment: That's right; I was just about to add a comment to that effect, but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

An exhaustive research of all the triples over a set with $2$ elements requires to verify $2^3=8$ different equations.

Instead, we may try with the method shown in [*Verification of Associativity of a Binary Operation* by S. Kamal Abdali](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3613856). From the Cayley table
\begin{array}{c|cc}
* & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
we get:
\begin{array}{c|cc}
* & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\\hline
\end{array}
then
\begin{array}{c|cc}
* & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 &   &  \\
1 &   & 0\\\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\\hline
\end{array}
and
\begin{array}{c|cc}
* & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 &   &  \\
1 &   &  \\\hline
0 &   & 1\\\hline
\end{array}
So, pretty quickly, we verified this operation to be associative.